# Space between widgets in QVBoxLayout

Tags: qt, spacing

I'm trying to make a sign-in form with Qt5.0.1. I created 2 Widgets and I put my labels and line edits in one of them, and my button in other one. Then I put these 2 widgets in a QVBoxLayout, but the space between two widget in layout is more than purpose. I tried setSpacing and setContentsMargin but they didn't work for this program.

```
vhandle->setSpacing(0);
vhandle->setMargin(0);
vhandle->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);
vhandle->addWidget(handle,0, Qt::AlignTop);
vhandle->addWidget(handle2,0, Qt::AlignTop);
```

but nothing changed in space between two widgets:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R33MM.png]

what should I do?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The issue is not the margin settings of the `QVboxLayout`, but the margin settings of the layout of your container widgets and the spacing setting of the QVBoxLayout. You already have set the spacing to 0, this should be fine. In addition, assumed that `upperWidgetLayout` is the layout of the upper widget and `lowerWidgetLayout` the layout of the lower widget, try

```
upperWidgetLayout->setContentsMargins(-1, -1, -1, 0);
lowerWidgetLayout->setContentsMargin(-1, 0, -1, -1);
```

This sets the bottom margin of the upper widget's layout and the top margin of the lower widget's layout to 0, so that there is no space between the contents of the two widgets:

[image: Dialog Layout]

Temporarily coloring the various widgets is usually a good approach to track down such issues. You can also use Qt Designer to design the UI and have a look at the source code which is being generated (or use the .ui file directly in your project).

Answer (score 1):

The extra space between widgets or layout can be removed by setting the alignment at top here is an example:

```
self.layout_scrollarea_v=QVBoxLayout(self.frame)
self.layout_scrollarea_v.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)
self.layout_scrollarea_v.addLayout(self.layout_scrollarea_h1)
self.layout_scrollarea_v.addLayout(self.layout_scrollarea_h3)
self.layout_scrollarea_v.addLayout(self.layout_scrollarea_h2)
```

in your code use

```
vhandle->setAlignment(Qt::AlignTop)
```