# QGraphicsScene disable setting right and bottom margin

Tags: c++, qt

I fit my scene for view's size, but it's content has some margins on right and bottom sides.

```
m_ui.graphicsView->fitInView(m_scene->sceneRect(), Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio);
```

Can I avoid this behavior?

[image]

Comment: Might be wrong, but depending on your used layouter where you put your graphics view in, this is a margin between the different elements. And if you use a QMainWindow the centralWidget also has a margin. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16572344/space-between-widgets-in-qvboxlayout) question and see if that helps you.

Comment: No, QGraphicalsView is in grid layout without margins, viewport also without it. This margin is inside view. I tryed set it. Maybe it is possible to set view resizeEvent filter on element? But I can't find any functions for it in QGraphicsItem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misunderstanding the point of the fitInView function. it's there to ensure that the given rect area of the scene is visible in the view. As the docs state: -

> Scales the view matrix and scrolls the scroll bars to ensure that the scene rectangle rect fits inside the viewport. rect must be inside the scene rect; otherwise, fitInView() cannot guarantee that the whole rect is visible.

Comment: You are right. However how can I scale the scenes content on all view and avoid this behavior?

Comment: How about trying the viewport function setFrameStyle(QFrame::NoFrame)?

Comment: Can you show a better image of what margin you're trying to remove; I don't think it's clear from a small corner?