# How to adjust space between layouts in a QVBoxLayout

Tags: python, layout, pyqt, spacing, qvboxlayout

I've seen how to adjust the space between widgets in a layout:
[Space between widgets in QVBoxLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16572344/space-between-widgets-in-qvboxlayout). However, I want to know how to adjust space between *layouts* added to a layout.

For example:

```
layout = QVBoxLayout()
h1_layout = QHBoxLayout()
h2_layout = QHBoxLayout()
layout.addLayout(h1_layout)
layout.addLayout(h2_layout)
```

I would like the contents of `h1_layout` and `h2_layout` to be placed close to each other rather than spaced across the vertical layout.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you want the contents of the two horizontal layouts to be aligned at the top of the vertical layout, and not stretched out to fill the entire space available. If so, you can achieve this by adding an expanding spacer to the bottom of the vertical layout:

```
layout = QVBoxLayout()
h1_layout = QHBoxLayout()
h2_layout = QHBoxLayout()
layout.addLayout(h1_layout)
layout.addLayout(h2_layout)
# add expanding spacer
layout.addStretch()
```

Another way to achieve a similar effect, is to set the alignment of the parent layout:

```
layout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
```

Comment: Thanks.  I actually found this method too.  However, for completeness, do you know of another way to achieve the desired effect?

Comment: @user3731622. I added an alternative solution

Comment: Both `addStretch` and `setAlighment` will put two layouts right next to each other. May I know if there is a way to set custom spacing? Thank you.

Comment: @ZhuokaiZhao Use `layout.setSpacing(10)` ([docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qboxlayout.html#setSpacing)), or add a fixed-width [spacer-item](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qspaceritem.html).